# What's the best use of the upgrade-vs-new tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Should the [upgrade-or-new-bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade-or-new-bike) tag be used to tag questions in the vein of "Should I buy a new bike or upgrade this bike?" or "This question is about a new bike or a bike I just upgraded"?

I happened to see a post tagged like the latter and think we should clarify a guideline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag should only be used for that first case. The second ("the question is about either A or B, but not both") is not how to properly use tags.

I reviewed site usage of that tag. The questions were all either about upgrading an existing bike, or about shopping for a new bike. I cleaned the tags up on all those questions. I also made "new-bike" a synonym for "shopping", figuring that's what a lot of people were trying to find when they applied that tag.

I also put this text in the tag summary:

> Making a choice between upgrading a bike you have or simply buying a new bike

If you can phrase that better, feel free to make a suggestion.

Comment: Looks good enough to me. Thanks!